# Array in array, angularJS, ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

im struggling with iterating over arrays in arrays. I need to create buttonlike vertical menu and cant get it work.

```js
angular.module('NavigationApp',[]).controller('NavigationController', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = [
        'Home',
        'Orders':
        {
            orders:['Orders', 'Open', 'Closed', 'New', 'Forgotten']
        },
        'Users',
        'Resources',
        'Settings',
        'Help'
    ];
    $scope.activeMenu = $scope.items[0];
    $scope.setActive = function(item) {
      $scope.activeMenu = item;
    };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="NavigationApp">
   <div class="col-md-3">
       <div ng-controller="NavigationController">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="filterQuery" />
           <ul class="list-group">
               <li ng-click="setActive(item)" ng-class="{active: activeMenu === item}" class="btn btn-lg list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterQuery"><a href="#">{{ item }}</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
    <script src="js/MainController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What i need to do is display array of items and while Orders item is active expand it with elements given in other array. To be honest i just dont know how to make it.

Comment: Any error in `console` ?

Comment: Try to represent your intent with a draw.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/h4jML9e.png
everything is button here, while order button is active it should display hidden elements

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `ng-repeat` over a heterogeneus array. i.e. it's elements are not all of the same type. The implementation logic needs to change here.

One thing you can do if your data structure is not flexible, is to use a `typeof item === 'object'` to filter out the object from the strings, or conversely check for `typeof` string

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick, basic example of what you could use:

```
$scope.items = [{
    name: 'Home'
}, {
    name: 'Orders',
    dropdown: [{
        name: 'Orders'
    }]
},{
    name: 'Users'
},
...
];
```

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterQuery" class="btn btn-lg list-group-item dropdown" ng-class="{active: activeMenu === item}" ng-click="setActive(item)">
    <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
        {{ item.name }} <span class="caret" ng-if="item.dropdown"></span>
    </a>
    <ul ng-if="item.dropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="dItem in item.dropdown">
            <a href="#">{{dItem.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I'd suggest having another indepth look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat to fully understand the structure required by the directive.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('NavigationApp',[]).controller('NavigationController', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = {
        main:['Home','Orders','Users','Resources','Settings','Help'],
        sub:['Open','Closed','New','Forgotten']
    };
    $scope.activeMenu = $scope.items[0];
    $scope.setActive = function(item) {
      $scope.activeMenu = item;
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="NavigationApp">
   <div class="col-md-3">
       <div ng-controller="NavigationController">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="filterQuery" />
           <ul class="list-group">
               <li ng-click="setActive(item)" ng-class="{active: activeMenu === item}" class="btn btn-lg list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in items.main | filter:filterQuery"><a href="#">{{ item }}</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="btn btn-lg list-group-item" ng-repeat="it in items.sub" ng-if="activeMenu === 'Orders'">{{it}}</li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
    <script src="js/MainController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is closer to what i want to achieve. But i dont know how to apply this nested UL to only one Li from parent list.

Answer (score 0):

this filter work correctly

INPUT :

```
['Home',{ 'Orders':{orders:['Orders', 'Open', 'Closed', 'New', 'Forgotten']}},'Users','Resources','Settings','Help']
```

OUTPUT :

```
 ["Home", "Orders", "Open", "Closed", "New", "Forgotten", "Users", "Resources", "Settings", "Help"]
```

```js
app.filter('customfilter', function () {
return function (data) {          
    function clean(item)
    {
      var result = [] ;
      // check if type is array
      if(Array.isArray(item)){
        // parse array
        item.forEach(function(i){
          result = result.concat(clean(i));
        })
      }// check if type is opject
      else if(typeof item =="object"){
          // parse opject
          Object.keys(item).map(function (key) {
             result = result.concat(clean(item[key]));
          });
      }else{
        result= [item]
      }
      return result ;
     } 
   return clean(data) ; 
 }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are so many ways to answer this question,although I've made a sample [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/H7huu9AJkk3b8emNEOuZ?p=preview) for your problem.Below is how your

HTML will look like

```
<body ng-app="NavigationApp">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div ng-controller="NavigationController">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="filterQuery" />
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li ng-click="setActive(item)" ng-class="{active: activeMenu === item}" class="btn btn-lg list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterQuery">
                    <a href="#">
                        <p ng-hide="item.dropdown"> {{ item.name }}</p>
                        <p ng-show="item.dropdown" ng-repeat="values in item.dropdown"> {{ values }}</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

JS look like

```
angular.module('NavigationApp', []).controller('NavigationController', function($scope) {

    var orderItemsObj = {
        orders: ['Orders', 'Open', 'Closed', 'New', 'Forgotten']
    };
    $scope.items = [{
        name: 'Home'
    }, {
        name: 'Orders',
        dropdown: ['Orders', 'Open', 'Closed', 'New', 'Forgotten']
    }, {
        name: 'Users'
    }, ];

    $scope.activeMenu = $scope.items[0];
    $scope.setActive = function(item) {
        $scope.activeMenu = item;
    };

});
```